# Decimal being stored as BigDecimal:4a58c60,'0.7484999999 999999E2',27(27) instead of 74.85

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal

I have a table that I created and one of the columns was created as:

```
t.decimal price
```

I created a new record by doing this:

```
Prices.create(:price => 74.85)
```

And the record created shows as this:

```
#<Price id: 10, price: #<BigDecimal:4925c58,'0.7484999999 999999E2',27(27)>>
```

Why would this happen? I would like to set 74.85 not 74.849999...

Thanks

Comment: What is the underlying DB? You may get variations in behaviour depending on how well the RDBMS supports decimals vs floats. If at any point the code converts a decimal to a `Float` and back again, you will see the `Float` approximation to the decimal you want. That could happen anywhere in the model, ORM, db driver or database. Starting off with a `Float` to convert, as you do in the OP, may  expose you to an underlying problem in any part of this.

Comment: I'm using Postgres...

Answer (score 1):

This is a floating point error. You can use a string instead:

```
Prices.create(:price => "74.85")
```

Note that this is not a Rails bug, it's the way floating point values and [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) work:

```
BigDecimal.new(74.85, 0)    #=> #<BigDecimal:7fc37cb7c068,'0.7484999999 9999994315 6581139191 98513031E2',45(54)>
BigDecimal.new("74.85")     #=> #<BigDecimal:7fc37ce69d48,'0.7485E2',18(18)>
```

Comment: It was suprising because when for example, doing 174.85, it gets stored correctly.

Comment: Stefan, when trying to do an update of that price and set price to '74.85' with a string, it stills shows me the old price with 74.849999